# What is the correct way to structure a Model class which accepts few arguments, but keeps the state of a larger JSON object?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a program which uses SQLAlchemy to interact with a database.

I have various model classes which represent the DB objects. These classes are all relatively similar, and hold a few fields which represent DB keys and columns which I know will be unchanged, but also have a JSON field to store the entire representation of the object.

I want to avoid strictly defining the model via the database schema as the Objects are often redefined, and updating the db definitions is an unnecessary time sink, and comes with upgrade issues.

Currently, my constructors accept a few arguments, and I have a class variable in each model representing the default JSON structure/values. The constructor generates several values from the input, and sets them in the JSON and updates the database tables.

My question is: Is this _DEFAULT_DEFINITION approach a safe way to define a JSON object structure for this class? Can anyone provide a more elegant alternative to this? As I feel it is a bit hackish.

Example:

```
import uuid

from datetime import datetime, timezone

from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite import JSON

from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncAttrs

class Example(DeclarativeBase, AsyncAttrs):
    __tablename__ = "examples"
    _DEFAULT_DEFINITION = {
        "one": "",
        "two": 2,
        "three": "",
        "four": "",
        "five": "five",
        "six": "six",
        "seven": [],
        "eight": [],
        "nine": "",
        "ten": "",
        "eleven": "",
        "twelve": 0,
        "thirteen": "thirteen",
        "fourteen": [],
        "fifteen": 15,
        "sixteen": [],
        "seventeen": {},
        "eighteen": ["eighteen"],
        "nineteen": "",
        "twenty": "",
        "twenty-one": "twenty-one",
        "twenty-two": 22,
        "twenty-three": 23,
        "twenty-four": "",
        "twenty-five": "",
    }

    one: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("otherTable.one"))
    three: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    example_json = mapped_column(JSON)

    def __init__(self, one: str):
        self.three = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.one = one

        self.example_json = self._DEFAULT_DEFINITION.copy()
        example_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        self.example_json.update(
            {
                "one": one,
                "three": self.three,
                "five": f"five/{self.three}",
                "nine": example_time,
            }
        )
```